# Where can I download the exercise data for The Free Quantum GIS Training Manual?

Tags: qgis, references

Where can I download the exercise data for The Free Quantum GIS Training Manual?
The pdf of the manual just mentions the sources of the data, but doesn't give any links.

Comment: Which manual? Please provide a link to the manual you are talking about.

Comment: I can't find data for this lesson: 9.4 Lesson: Supplementary Exercise. can anybody help me? thanks

Comment: @underdark. i did not find any data regarding the supplementary exercise in that folder. you can check it in 9.4.2 section in training_manual but the folder called more_analysis does not exist in exercise data folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you talk about this manual: http://manual.linfiniti.com/

You will find the data here:

> https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Training-Manual/tree/master/exercise_data

Comment: Yes, that is the manual I was talking about. Thank you for the link.

Comment: link now broken

Comment: True, see the more recent answer of Erve1879.

Answer (score 7):

**As of February 2014, the QGIS Training Manual has been updated to match QGIS 2.x. The manual has also been moved.**

The online manual can be found here:

http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/training_manual/index.html

and the exercise data can be downloaded here:

http://qgis.org/downloads/data/

A downloadable PDF version will be made available soon.

Answer (score 5):

While working on publishing a print copy of this manual, I decided to post **a single zip file** (41MB) of all the exercise data to make this a bit more convenient:

- Latest will always be linked from [our book info page](http://www.locatepress.com/books/qgis-training)
- Or download [the zip file directly](http://www.locatepress.com/files/qgis-training/exercise_data.zip)

Answer (score 0):

This one has tutorial plus exercise data. Hope it may help you. 
http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/

Update:

[This one](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/making_a_map.html) is the first basic tutorial with data download.

Download the [Natural Earth Quickstart Kit](http://kelso.it/x/nequickstart). Size: ~157 mb

Comment: @Martin Basically you are right, but the asker wanted a download link for the data. If the linked page changes, someone has to update it here too.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still interested in this issue - the qgis tutorial exercises are worth doing - then data for exercise 9.4 is available as mentioned above. However the admin districts data is missing, or at least it has only one district in the dataset. I have found that the admin district data is available free in a larger set of district data from DIVA_GIS at http://www.diva-gis.org/datadown. There are three shapefiles in the download ZAF_adm.zip, and the third one ZAF_adm2 contains the Cape Town districts mentioned in the tutorial exercise. I have yet to complete the tutorial so cannot confirm that the data meets the full requirements. I shall edit this when I know.